# Running WhatsApp in Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, android, emulator

Is there any way I can run [WhatsApp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp) on Fedora? There are Android emulators like [BlueStackApps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueStacks) for Windows and Mac, but I haven't found one for Fedora or Ubuntu.

Is there any such that will allow me to run Android application like [WhatsApp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp) on Fedora ?

*Note: I am looking for answers other than recommending android emulator that is part of the SDk*

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to use whatsapp in my computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/1035008/is-it-possible-to-use-whatsapp-in-my-computer)

Answer (score 1):

[Whatsapp has a web client](https://web.whatsapp.com/) that can run on any computer.

You will need to have created a WhatsApp account on your phone first.  Then when you use the web app for the first time you need to link it to your phone account using the bar code on the screen.

The web app is limited to run on a single device at a time.   If you log in from another computer, it will log you out of any others.

I like it running in its own window outside my normal web browser.   Google chrome has an "app" mode for just this kind of thing.   I start whatsapp with the following command line to give it its own window and task bar icon:

```
google-chrome --password-store=basic --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run things through the Android emulator, part of the Android SDK (software development kit).

This provides a virtual device which does allow you to run quite a lot of Android applications though it may struggle with some of the more hardware-dependent things (3D, Phone calls, GPS, SMS, etc)

Here's a guide on getting it set up:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Run-Android-Applications-on-Ubuntu-115152.shtml

A detailed SDK install guide can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Comment: can it be other than android emulator part of SDK. I guess that emulator is not abstracted for this.

Answer (score 0):

snapd makes available the whatsdesk package which seems to be fully functional:

```
$ snap info whatsdesk
name:      whatsdesk
summary:   whatsdesk
publisher: Gustavo Gonzalez (zerkc)
contact:   incoming+zerkc/whatsdesk@incoming.gitlab.com
license:   unset
description: |
  unofficial whatsapp client for linux
commands:
  - whatsdesk
snap-id:      M7gg5zVdwlMpELFowEYDELP5Us8G9Cjw
tracking:     stable
refresh-date: 2019-09-26
channels:
  stable:    0.2.18 2019-04-25 (17) 109MB -
  candidate: ↑                            
  beta:      ↑                            
  edge:      ↑                            
installed:   0.2.18            (17) 109MB -
```