# Is it possible to use Whatsapp without an Apple or Android phone device?

Tags: whatsapp

For example, I have a laptop running Windows 8. Is there any way I can run Whatsapp through my laptop?

I also have a Dell tablet that uses an Android based operating system, but does not have 3G/data.

Comment: See also: [Running WhatsApp in Fedora](http://superuser.com/questions/459534/running-whatsapp-in-fedora)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to Bluestacks is hosting a Android virtual machine, like AndroVM on VirtualBox. I think it is a better and less intrusive solution.
If you don't have a real Android device to "activate" WhatsApp, this is how you can activate it on your virtual machine:

1. Start the authentication process on your WhatsApp in virtual machine.
2. When required, enter a valid number, one that you have access to.
3. When being prompt, mark that you prefer a voice call over SMS
4. Write down the activation code into the emulated WhatsApp

Alternatively:

1. use your phone's number and receive the SMS message there
2. Install an fake sms app on your Android virtual machine
3. Create a fake SMS EXACTLY like the one you got on your phone
4. Wait for WhatsApp to activate

Comment: Can you elaborate on "an fake sms"?

Comment: there are many apps in the store which can create fake sms. you can choose one. what they do is basically create a sms message on your phone, like you've received it.

Comment: I assume it's simpler and quicker to just choose a phone call over SMS and maually type the digits you get into the app. This will even allow you to use a landline number and thus not break the WhatsApp installation you already have in your real device (you can only have 1 WhatsApp per number).

Comment: true. will work too.

Comment: In that case, I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.  You can actually install an Android emulator and then run WhatsApp from the emulator:

1. Download the Bluestacks Emulator On Your Pc from link given above.
2. Install Bluestacks App Player on your Pc and then login with your Gmail ID.
3. Now click on Search icon or click on My Apps and then App Search.
4. Now search for WhatsApp and then many apps will appear with the apps sharing the same keyword.
5. Now select the official WhatsApp and then it will start searching for App Stores on the web from where you can download WhatsApp and install it on Pc.
6. Now choose one of the working App Stores and WhatsApp will start downloading and installing.
7. So now WhatsApp is available in your App Drawer,you can just head there and open it.
8. You can configure it using your Phone No and start chatting with your friends.

SOURCE:
[How To Download WhatsApp For Pc,WhatsApp For Windows 7/8/XP](http://whatsappforpc.in/download-whatsapp-for-pc-whatsapp-for-windows-7-8-xp/)

Answer (score 0):

Both the above answer are correct, however I would like to add that you can try any android emulator not to run whatsapp (or any android app) on your PC. For instance you can try andy, youwave, bluestacks, manymo (this works online in the browser) and even android OS using virtual box.

And for tablet you can use download whatsapp latest apk from their official website and install it on your WiFi tablet. Ignore warning if you get any. Source: Using whatsapp on my nexux7 tablet from 2 years.