# Is it possible to use WhatsApp on PC completely without a smartphone?

Tags: windows, whatsapp, web-whatsapp

There is a WhatsApp version for PCs (Windows) which can be linked with WhatsApp on a smartphone. It requires a WhatsApp mobile version already running. However, some users have managed to register with their landline number at WhatsApp ([see here](https://www.gadgetsnow.com/how-to/how-to-use-whatsapp-using-a-landline-number-without-revealing-your-mobile-number/articleshow/69393882.cms)).

An alternative could be to register with my mobile number, receive the SMS, and use this account. I have a very old mobile phone, but NO smartphone.

The missing part now is how to link this account with the PC version. Has someone managed to do so? Or found an alternative way?

Comment: Nope, you need a phone/app to get the web/PC version logged in. The link refers to a 'different' app/version meant for businesses.

Comment: I wonder if running android on a VM would be an option.

Comment: I had the same and I am about to figure out if I need to emulate a phone number SIM card for that.

Comment: Just found this one, VM approach seems possible: https://superuser.com/q/799927/72397

Comment: IIRC I've activated it on a phone without a line - just need to key in the activation code it gives via SMS